# How do I suppress warnings for autocorrect and autocapitalize attributes in MVC Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, attributes, suppress-warnings

In my Razor view I specify the form tag like this:

```
<form autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off">
```

The autocorrect and autocapitalize attributes are for iPhones but generate warnings when building the application. The view is a HTML5 view.

How can I suppress the warnings? I know I can turn off the warnings in HTML Validation options but ideally I would just like to tell the compiler that autocorrect and autocapitalize are valid attributes and not to show warnings for them.